# Remove line in text files that contain a certain words in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to remove every lines in a text file that contain the word "script" and then write whatever left into another file. But keep the originl file.

like this:

open the file
delete any line with the word "script"
then output whatever left after delete to another file.

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -ne '/script/ or print' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v script original.file > new.file
```

Or if you really need perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'input.txt')
    or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";

open(my $out, '>', 'output.txt')
    or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";

while (<$in>) {
  print $out $_ unless /script/;
}

close($in);
close($out);
```

Finally, if you are only looking to match "script" if it is a word (and not part of a bigger string like "prescription" or "scripting") then change:

```
/script/
```

To:

```
/\bscript\b/
```